# Constructing stream witout copying buffer

Tags: c++

I have a code like:

```
char* text = ....
std::istringstream iss(text);
```

I know that here temporary std::string is constructed and it one more time is copied inside stringstream object. Is there a way to construct stream from char* without making copy of string.

Comment: No there is none. You can create a stringstream/string "on" on a char*. You may look at `std::string_view` which will probably be in the c++17 standard.

Comment: OK Thanks. Actually solution is not necessary need to deal with std::string and std::stringstream. Maybe there is something in boost or other libraries? stringstream here is used only for getline. Even extraction operators are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, this functionality was provided by the now deprecated [`std::istrstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/istrstream):

> The class `istrstream` implements input operations on array-backed
>   streams. It essentially wraps a raw array I/O device implementation
>   (`std::strstreambuf`) into the higher-level interface of
>   `std::basic_istream`.
>
> The typical implementation of `istrstream` holds only one non-derived
>   data member: an object of type `std::strstreambuf`.
>
> #### Notes
>
> `istrstream` has been deprecated since C++98, `std::istringstream` and
>   **`boost::iostreams::array_source`** are the recommended replacements.

Thus, a current implementation meeting your requirements is [`boost::iostreams::array_source`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html#array_source):

> #### Overview
>
> The class templates `basic_array_source`, `basic_array_sink` and
>   `basic_array` provide access to a sequence of characters in memory. The
>   array Devices do not manage the lifetimes of the underlying character
>   sequences.
>
> #### Implementation
>
> The array Devices are implemented as Direct Devices in order to
>   provide efficient unbuffered access to the underlying character
>   sequences.