# Fastest Way to Read a File Into Memory in c++?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm trying to read from a file in a faster way. The current way I'm doing it is the following, but it is very slow for large files. I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this? I need the values stored a struct, which I have defined below.

```
std::vector<matEntry> matEntries;
inputfileA.open(matrixAfilename.c_str());

// Read from file to continue setting up sparse matrix A
while (!inputfileA.eof()) {
    // Read row, column, and value into vector
    inputfileA >> (int) row; // row
    inputfileA >> (int) col; // col
    inputfileA >> val;       // value

    // Add row, column, and value entry to the matrix
    matEntries.push_back(matEntry());
    matEntries[index].row = row-1;
    matEntries[index].col = col-1;
    matEntries[index].val = val;

    // Increment index
    index++;
}
```

my struct:

```
struct matEntry {
    int row;
    int col;
    float val;
};
```

The file is formatted like this (int, int, float):

```
1 2 7.9
4 5 9.008
6 3 7.89
10 4 10.21
```

More info:

- I know the number of lines in the file at run time.
- I am facing a bottleneck. The profiler says the while() loop is the bottleneck.

Comment: **Are you facing a bottleneck?** This is generally considered the 'fastest' way, though [`mmap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) might be another option depending on how you're using the file's contents.

Comment: Which part did your profiler say was slow?  File reads?  `vector` reallocations?  `fstream` operations?

Comment: @genpfault, **the while loop is the slow part**

Comment: @Qix, **Yes**, a majority of my program's execution time is just parsing the file and storing the values from the file into my data structure.

Comment: Platform specific: memory map the file.

Comment: Can you change the format of the input file? If you can store everything in binary, then read them back in binary.

Comment: @TonyJ, I am looking for another way besides changing the format of the files.

Comment: Do you know the number of lines of the file?

Comment: @NaCl, I know the number of lines in the file at run time.

Comment: Your profiler might say that the while loop is taking the majority of the execution time but **that's to be expected**. *Something* has to take up execution time, or your program wouldn't be running. That doesn't mean your while loop is a bottleneck. A bottleneck means something is causing more of a slowdown than would be expected or considered most optimal.

Comment: Re: `while (!eof)` http://stackoverflow.com/q/21647/1538531

Comment: Of course the `while` loop is identified as the slow part, because *all* of the work is being done within the loop! You need a little more granularity.

Comment: See my updated answer for some alternatives and higher-level questions.

Comment: All the answers are good, but from my experience the biggest bottleneck is usually reading the file from hard drive. Unfortunately, you just can't optimized it(much). Assuming you can change the file format, consider storing the data in binary and/or compressed the file, although compressing floating point values maybe not produce great compression ratio.

Answer (score 3):

To make things easier, I'd define an input stream operator for your struct.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, matEntry& e)
{
    is >> e.row >> e.col >> e.val;
    e.row -= 1;
    e.col -= 1;

    return is;
}
```

Regarding speed, there is not much to improve without going to a [very basic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755132/3187621) level of file IO. I think the only thing you could do is to initialize your vector such that it doesn't resize all the time inside the loop. And with the defined input stream operator it looks much cleaner as well:

```
std::vector<matEntry> matEntries;
matEntries.resize(numberOfLines);
inputfileA.open(matrixAfilename.c_str());

// Read from file to continue setting up sparse matrix A
while(index < numberOfLines && (is >> matEntries[index++]))
{  }
```

Comment: By defining a custom operator like that, you can then remove the manual loop completely by using [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) with [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), eg: `std::vector<matEntry> matEntries; matEntries.reserve(numberOfLines); std::copy(std::istream_iterator<matEntry>(inputfileA), std::istream_iterator<matEntry>(), std::back_inserter(matEntries));`

Comment: or [`std::copy_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) in C++11 and later, eg: `std::vector<matEntry> matEntries; matEntries.reserve(numberOfLines); std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<matEntry>(inputfileA), numberOfLines, std::back_inserter(matEntries));`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, you should profile your code before trying to optimize. If you want to try random stuff until the performance is good enough, you can try reading it into memory first. Here's a simple example with some basic profiling written in:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// Assuming something like this...
struct matEntry
{
    int row, col;
    double val;
};

std::istream& operator << ( std::istream& is, matEntry& e )
{ 
    is >> matEntry.row >> matEntry.col >> matEntry.val;
    matEntry.row -= 1;
    matEntry.col -= 1;
    return is;
}


std::vector<matEntry> ReadMatrices( std::istream& stream )
{
    auto matEntries = std::vector<matEntry>();

    auto e = matEntry();
    // For why this is better than your EOF test, see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-while
    while( stream >> e ) {
        matEntries.push_back( e );
    }
    return matEntries;
}

int main()
{
    const auto time0 = std::clock();

    // Read file a piece at a time
    std::ifstream inputFileA( "matFileA.txt" );
    const auto matA = ReadMatrices( inputFileA );

    const auto time1 = std::clock();

    // Read file into memory (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2602258/201787)
    std::ifstream inputFileB( "matFileB.txt" );
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << inputFileB.rdbuf();
    const auto matB = ReadMatrices( buffer );

    const auto time2 = std::clock();
    std::cout << "A: " << ((time1 - time0) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "  B: " << ((time2 - time1) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "\n";
    std::cout << matA.size() << " " << matB.size();
}
```

Beware reading the same file on disk twice in a row since the disk caching may hide performance differences.

Other options include:

- Preallocate space in your vector (perhaps adding a size to file format or estimating it based on file size or something)
- Change your file format to be binary or perhaps compressed data to minimize read time
- Memory map the file
- Parallelize (*easy*: process file A and file B in separate threads [see `std::async()`]; *medium*: pipeline it so the read and convert are done on different threads; *hard*: process the same file in separate threads)

Other higher-level considerations might include:

- It looks like you have a 4-D array of data (rows/cols of 2D matrices). In many applications, this is a mistake. Take a moment to reconsider if this data structure is really what you need.
- There are many high-quality matrix libraries available (e.g., [Boost.QVM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/qvm/doc/index.html), [Blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze), etc.). Use them rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, loading the entire file into stringstream(assuming there is enough memory), then parsing could be faster, because it avoids spinning the hard drive to seek to the file again.

Comment: Generally there are two slow parts to I/O: the disk read itself, and the translation from text to binary. The disk read doesn't show up in profilers because it happens in the OS, and the text to binary will be the same for both the methods presented in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the slowest part in such code is the parsing of numeric  values (especially the floating point ones). Therefore your code is most probably CPU-bound and can be sped-up through parallelization as follows:

Assuming that your data is on **N** lines and you are going to process it using **k** threads, each thread will have to handle about [**N**/**k**] lines.

1. `mmap()` the file.
2. Scan the entire file for newline symbols and identify the range that you are going to assign to every thread.
3. Let each thread process its range in parallel by using an [implementation of an `std::istream` that wraps an in-memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520504/constructing-stream-witout-copying-buffer)).

Note that this will require ensuring that the code for populating your data structure is thread safe.